# PHP - Trouble adding value to third dimensional array

Tags: php

I have a this array scenario at first:

```
$_SESSION['player_1_pawn'][] = 'Warrior';
```

now when I want to add a third dimensional value like this:

```
$_SESSION['player_1_pawn'][0]['x'] = 1;
```

I get this output from

```
>$_SESSION['player_1_pawn'][0] : '1arrior'
```

My question is that, how to make that value stays intact as `Warrior` instead of `1arrior`?

Answer (score 6):

If the value is already a string, `['x']` accesses the first character of that string (yeah, don't ask ;)).

If you want to replace the whole thing with an array, do:

```
$_SESSION['player_1_pawn'][0] = array('x' => 1);
```

You cannot have `$_SESSION['player_1_pawn'][0]` be both the string "Warrior" *and* an array at the same time, so figure out which you want it to be. Probably:

```
$_SESSION['player_1_pawn'][0] = array('type' => 'Warrior', 'x' => 1);
```

Comment: Damn you are faaaaaaaaast :), however the [0] doesn't access the first character in his case, it was the 'x'

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `$_SESSION['player_1_pawn'][0]` is a scalar value equal to "Warrior".  When you treat a scalar as an array, like you do with `$_SESSION['player_1_pawn'][0]['x']` which evalueates `$_SESSION['player_1_pawn'][0][0]` or "W", you just change the first character in the string.

If you want to keep "Warrior" try this:

```
$_SESSION['player_1_pawn']=array('Warrior', 'x'=>1);
```

ETA:

given your requirements, the structure is this:

```
$_SESSION['player_1_pawn'] = array(
  0 => array('Warrior', 'x'=>1),
  1 => array('Wizard', 'x'=>7), //...
);
```

Which means you add like this:

```
$_SESSION['player_1_pawn'][]=array('Warrior', 'x'=>1);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it needs to be at least two dimension since player 1 has got not only 1 pawn but 5 :D